# Split array into subarrays by summed up value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of hashes, where every hash has a `size` key:

```
blocks = [{size: 1},{size: 3},{size: 4}]
```

Now I want to split this array into subarrays by aggregating the `size` value, and defining an upper limit of `4`. In every subarray the summed up values of the `size` key should be less than `4`.

I have this solution, but it's not pretty or elegant:

```
arr = []
tmp = []
sum = 0

blocks.each do |block|
  sum += block[:size]
  tmp.push(block)
  if sum >= 4
    arr.push(tmp)
    sum = 0
    tmp = []
  end
end
```

Maybe someone knows a more ruby-like, elegant solution.

Comment: Take a look at [codereview.se]. Stack Overflow is for solutions where code doesn't work. Code Review is for working code you have written that you want to improve.

Comment: I'd say you need to rework your `blocks` array. An array of single key/value pair hashes is awkward and results in a more awkward algorithm. Clean it up before processing, either where it's generated or using a `map` to get only the values. `blocks.map(&:pop) {` instead of the `each do` perhaps

Comment: Thanks for the hint to Code Review (btw: is it possible to transfer the question to Code Review?)

For the real use case, I have activerecord objects with properties (I just converted it into hashes, so that it's easier to understand). What do you mean by *An array of single key/value pair hashes is awkward and results in a more awkward algorithm* ?

Comment: You close the question and ask it on Code Review.

Comment: I wish there was a migration pattern for this since it seems to happen a lot. I would dare to say CodeReview would be more useful here than say meta or even superuser.

Comment: Maybe you could create a kata on [Codewars](http://www.codewars.com/).  I'm sure you'll get there clever solutions

Answer (score 2):

There is a way using [slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when):

```
sum = 0
blocks.slice_when do |elt_before, _|
  sum += elt_before[:size]
  sum >= 4 ? (sum = 0; true) : false
end.to_a
```

---

**Edit: As per @CarySwoveland suggestion**

It can get even simpler if using [slice_after](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after):

```
sum = 0
blocks.slice_after do |elt|
  sum += elt[:size]
  sum >= 4 ? (sum = 0; true) : false
end.to_a
```

As a note both `slice_when` & `slice_after` first appeared in Ruby v.2.2

Comment: Nice one. It can be simplified by replacing the second and third lines with `blocks.slice_after do |elt|; sum += elt[:size]`. I think that reads a bit better as well. It should be mentioned that both `slice_when` and  [Enumerable#slice_after](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after) first appeared in Ruby v.2.2.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for pointing out! I'll update the answer with the info you provided